# Deserialize XML object. Fields are not initialized

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

There is a problem, that the object fields are initialized as null.

I've checked a couple of examples, I've set the field annotations, but seems like I did something wrong.

So here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getInvoiceReply>
    <invoiceID value="944659502"/>
    <invFastener>
        <fastenerID value=""/>
        <fastenerName value=""/>
        <fastenerCount value=""/>
        <fastenerProperty>
            <propID value=""/>
            <propName value=""/>
            <propValue value=""/>
        </fastenerProperty>
    </invFastener>
</getInvoiceReply>
```

I've created the class hierarcy.

Root class `InvoiceReply` :

```
 [XmlRoot("getInvoiceReply")]
    public class InvoiceReply
    {
        [XmlAttribute("invoiceID")]
        public string InvoiceId { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("invFastener")]
        public List<InvFastener> InvFastener { get; set; }
    }
```

class `InvFastener` :

```
public class InvFastener
    {
        [XmlAttribute("fastenerID")]
        public string FastenerID { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("fastenerName")]
        public string FastenerName { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("fastenerCount")]
        public string FastenerCount { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("fastenerProperty")]
        public List<FastenerProperty> FastenerProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

class `FastenerProperty`:

```
public class FastenerProperty
    {
        [XmlAttribute("propID")]
        public string PropId { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("propName")]
        public string PropName { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("propValue")]
        public string PropValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Test code:

```
 InvoiceReply i = null;

 var serializer =  new XmlSerializer(typeof(InvoiceReply));
 using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("C:\\filePathHere\\test.xml"))
     {
        i = (InvoiceReply)serializer.Deserialize(reader);      
     }
```

[image]

Could anyone please suggest why is this happens?

Comment: In your post, the sample XML only has a value for invoiceID. Are you using another sample that has more data in it? If so, can we see that sample?

Comment: XmlAttribute("fastenerID") fastenerID is an element, value is the attribute. You have this for multiple elements

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I am using the same. There might be some numbers, nothing special. Maybe problem that "value" for each element is attribute? Maybe my hierarchy is wrong ?

Comment: Well, at first glance, I mean... there are no values.  So I'd take a strong guess that this is why they end up being null.

Comment: @bhmahler that means that InvoiceId should be the class with the field called "Value" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with your objects.  You are trying to get attributes in place of elements and your arrays are not arrays, they are merely complex elements. Below is a working example that matches your xml schema

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
        <getInvoiceReply>
            <invoiceID value=""944659502""/>
            <invFastener>
                <fastenerID value=""""/>
                <fastenerName value=""""/>
                <fastenerCount value=""""/>
                <fastenerProperty>
                    <propID value=""""/>
                    <propName value=""""/>
                    <propValue value=""""/>
                </fastenerProperty>
            </invFastener>
        </getInvoiceReply>";



        var serializer =  new XmlSerializer(typeof(InvoiceReply));
        var i = (InvoiceReply)serializer.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)));  

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

//Generic class for getting value attribute
public class ValueElement
{
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("getInvoiceReply")]
public class InvoiceReply
{
    [XmlElement("invoiceID")]
    public ValueElement InvoiceId { get; set; } //This is a value element

    [XmlElement("invFastener")]
    public List<InvFastener> InvFastener { get; set; } //This is an element, not an array
}

public class InvFastener
{
    [XmlElement("fastenerID")]
    public ValueElement FastenerID { get; set; }//This is a value element

    [XmlElement("fastenerName")]
    public ValueElement FastenerName { get; set; }//This is a value element

    [XmlElement("fastenerCount")]
    public ValueElement FastenerCount { get; set; }//This is a value element

    [XmlElement("fastenerProperty")]
    public List<FastenerProperty> FastenerProperties { get; set; } //This is an element, not an array
}

public class FastenerProperty
{
    [XmlElement("propID")]
    public ValueElement PropId { get; set; }//This is a value element

    [XmlElement("propName")]
    public ValueElement PropName { get; set; }//This is a value element

    [XmlElement("propValue")]
    public ValueElement PropValue { get; set; }//This is a value element
}
```

Comment: Sir, thanks for help. May I ask you one more question? What if there would be another <invFastener> tag right after <invFastener>? Would it be parsable ? In source xml file they are not rounded by parent tag. And they might be from (0..n) They are going one by one.

Comment: Just leave it as XmlElement and change the type to list `public List<InvFastener> InvFastener { get; set; }` I updated my answer to support multiple InvFastener and Multiple FastenerProperties